# Yii2 CORS with Auth not working for non CRUD actions

Tags: php, rest, yii2, cors

I am building an API in Yii2 and have added CORS and authentication. This works fine for all Create/Read/Update/Delete actions but not for custom actions. Has anyone experienced this before?

URL manager:

```
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'api/v1/user', 'pluralize' => false],
```

Controller behaviors:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge([
            'corsFilter' => [
                'class' => Cors::className(),
            ],
            [
                'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                'except' => ['options',
                             'login',
                ],
            ],
        ], parent::behaviors()
    );
}
```

As mentioned, actions for CRUD are fine but a custom action such as `http://domain.com/user/test` will respond with a `401 Unauthorised` response.

Is it not possible to get CORS and auth to work together on custom actions?

Edit: I should add that the issue (401) occurs only when a browser makes the `OPTIONS` request. Normal requests (curl,Postman) are not affected. The issue seems to occur with the RESTful,Cors,Auth combination.

Comment: what is the full error message dropped in browser's console ?

Comment: also what controller are you extending `\yii\rest\ActiveController` or `\yii\rest\Controller` ? did you override or changed the way how the built-in `options` actions is working ?

Comment: @salem, I am extending ActiveController.

Comment: @Salem, the browser console shows: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://poly.api/api/v1/user/me. Invalid HTTP status code 401`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
        ],
    ];

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' =>  HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        'except' => ['options','login'],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

It will **unset** the default `authenticator` implemented by the [parent controller](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/Controller.php#L46) to be sure that `cors` is treated first. Then we force `cors` to allow credentials before implementing your own `authenticator`.

---

The other thing that may raise that **Unauthorized** error is a not-found or wrong `Options` response as a browser request it first to get a list of allowed verbs. You may check that list in its headers response within your browser's network tab.

The general rule is when you ask your browser to perform a sensible verb like PUT, DELETE or POST to any **url** it may first send an OPTIONS request to that same **url** (*check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request#answer-13030629)*) to check if that verb is allowed before sending the real request. So Yii should be configured to respond to all those OPTIONS verbs by performing the correct redirections.

The default CRUD actions implemented by `ActiveController` are using those [default patterns](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/UrlRule.php#L115-L123):

```
'PUT,PATCH {id}' => 'update',
'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
'GET,HEAD {id}' => 'view',
'POST' => 'create',
'GET,HEAD' => 'index',
'{id}' => 'options',
'' => 'options',
```

So whatever configurations you did implement in `urlManager['rules']` be sure to not override the last 2 of them and if you are using custom patterns always remember to include its equivalent `options` verbs like in this example:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
    'controller' => ['account' => 'auth/account'], 
    'patterns' => [
        'POST,HEAD login'  => 'login',
        'POST,HEAD signup' => 'signup',
        'POST req-reset-pass' => 'request-password-reset',
        'POST reset-pass' => 'reset-password',
        // OPTTIONS VERBS
        'OPTIONS login' => 'options',
        'OPTIONS signup' => 'options',
        'OPTIONS req-reset-pass' => 'options',
        'OPTIONS reset-pass' => 'options',
    ]
],
```

The same applies when adding custom patterns within **extraPatterns**.

---

The `Options` action is implemented by default in `ActiveController`. it's code can be seen [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/OptionsAction.php). 
In case you are extending a different controller than `ActiveController` like maybe `\yii\rest\Controller` be sure to manually include it:

```
public function actions() 
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    $actions['options'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\OptionsAction',
        // optional:
        'collectionOptions' => ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
        'resourceOptions' => ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
    ];
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: FIXED. Thanks so much for the thorough response. This had caused me so much pain. It was adding the patterns declaration to the URL manager that fixed it. I am forever grateful.

Comment: I have just discovered that when I added the `patterns` attribute to the urlManager it has broken to `update` functionality (`PUT user/1` for example). Now when I attempt to update I get a `404 response`. Removing the patterns attribute corrects this. I can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I got around the issue mentioned directly above by adding another pattern `'PUT,PATCH {id}' => 'update',`.

Answer (score 1):

Just move your corsFilter block above the authenticator block like this:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'corsFilter' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            ],
            'authenticator' => [
                'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            ],
            'contentNegotiator' => [
                'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
                'formats' => [
                    'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ],
            ],

        ];
    }
```